# Header inside div goes outside after clicking elements

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I have 3 containers with a min-height of `100vh`. When clicking an svg-arrow that scrolls down to the next page, the header within the second container gets pushed out, resulting in the entire div pushed up in view.

```css
body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Main Section */

.intro-main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: block;
  min-height: 15vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header-nav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #ffbbbb;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.intro-name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.intro-paragrapgh {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.down-arrow-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -88%;
}

.first-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Project Sectoin */

.main-project-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.project-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 85vh;
}

.project-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.project-name-link {
  font-family: "Padauk", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: $pinkish;
}

.project-description {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.project-desc {
  text-align: center;
  color: $pinkish;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.down-arrow-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  right: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Contact */

.main-contact-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.forms-container {
  min-height: 65vh;
  position: relative;
}

.contact-links-container {
  min-height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="intro-main-container">
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1><a id="home" href="./index.html" class="header-nav">HOME</a></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="intro">
      <header>
        <h2 class="intro-name">Jon <br />Doe</h2>
      </header>

      <p class="intro-paragrapgh"> web developer</p>

    </div>

    <div class="down-arrow-container">
      <a href="#project" class="first-arrow">
        <svg class="arrow-point" width="46" height="46" viewBox="0 0 46 46" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <circle cx="23" cy="23" r="23" fill="#434343" />
              <path
                d="M14 23.1773L23 34.2956L32 23.1773"
                stroke="#FFBBBB"
                stroke-width="4"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              />
              <path
                d="M23 32.7073V11"
                stroke="#FFBBBB"
                stroke-width="4"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              />
            </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="main-project-container">
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1>
        <a id="project" href="#project" class="header-nav">PROJECTS</a>
      </h1>
    </header>

    <div class="project-container">
      <div class="project-name">
        <a href="#project" class="project-name-link">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a
            >
          </div>
        

          <div class="project-description">
            <a href="" class="project-desc">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="down-arrow-2">
          <a href="#contact">
            <svg
              class="arrow-point"
              width="46"
              height="46"
              viewBox="0 0 46 46"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <circle cx="23" cy="23" r="23" fill="#434343" />
              <path
                d="M14 23.1773L23 34.2956L32 23.1773"
                stroke="#FFBBBB"
                stroke-width="4"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              />
              <path
                d="M23 32.7073V11"
                stroke="#FFBBBB"
                stroke-width="4"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
              />
            </svg>
          </a>
      </div>
  </section>

  <section class="main-contact-container">
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1>
        <a id="contact" href="#contact" class="header-nav">CONTACT</a>
      </h1>
    </header>

    <div class="forms-container"></div>

    <div class="contact-links-container"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

`.main-header` is no longer centered in `.main-project-container` and the header is pushed to the top of the 2nd container. More noticeable in mobile-view.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I really can't see the issue you're talking about. Try clearing your **cache** and try it this way.

Comment: @ZombieChowder if you select the .main-project-container after clicking the arrow in inspect the header box goes outside the container

Comment: Removing `overflow-y: hidden` seems to fix it. Though, it really doesn't seem like an issue worth worrying about